# Is there a way to safely include admin views in Angular (or any SPA for that matter)?

Tags: angular, security, single-page-application

I'm currently developing an application that uses ASP Web Api for the backend and Angular4 for the frontend. Currently I'm creating an admin component for the frontend, but this feels wrong to me. A user who knows his way around developer tools, could simply check the source code for the available routes. With just a little tinkering, he would then be able to view the admin pages on the frontend.

I know that security matters most at the backend and I'm positive that the app is well secured, but I just cannot believe it's good practice to keep the admin views so open.

I'm interested on hearing your opinion on the matter and if you have any suggestions that I did not yet think of.

Comment: You can not secure the app, what you should do is secure the data. Anyone with a bit of knowledge could access your admin app, but if the data is secure they will see an empty app as the server will reject the user.

Comment: @Ploppy I understand that and that's true, but still, a visitor could for example see the exact screen that I use to modify a user's credentials / change roles etc... Is that something that I should just accept because I know the backend is secured? Like I said before... it just doesn't feel right...

Comment: You just have to accept it, though angular offers routeGuards which can prevent unauthorized users to reach a given page. Though it's always possible to bypass it, as it is impossible to secure a clientside app.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that even if the user know his way around dev tools, he wouldn't be able to access admin pages.

First, your code is minified. He needs to be really good to be able to modify it.

Second, Even if he does success, refreshing the page will make him lose all his modifications.

Third, (I assume that your admin views are making http calls) you should secure your endpoints to only allow verified admins to be able to make http calls. This means that if the user can see the admin page, he won't be able to change your data, no matter what he does.

I hope this hepled you !